# Swap key/value in object - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object

I want swap key(s) in an object with value(s) and swap value(s) with key(s)

`{name:"Mohammad",age:"29"} ==>>  {Mohammad:"name",29:"age"`}

Below code work:

```
function swap(oldObj) {
let newObj = {};
for (let i in oldObj) {
    newObj[oldObj[i]] = i;
     }
return newObj;
}
```

since below code log values(s) in an object:

**Actually obj[i] is object's value(S)**

```
function objValue (obj){
    for (let i in obj){
        console.log(obj[i]);
    }
}
```

I changed swap function (first block code) to:

```
function swap(oldObj) {
    let newObj = {};
    for (let i in oldObj) {
        newObj.oldObj[i] = i;
         }
    return newObj;
    }
```

Actually I try call oldObj's value(s) with `oldObj[i]` and add this as key to newObj with `newObj.oldObj[i]` instead of `newObj[oldObj[i]]`
but error occur

```
Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'name')
```

Comment: `newObj.oldObj[i] = i` <- this line won't work. Your first version `newObj[oldObj[i]] = i` is correct. I don't understand what are you asking about. Your first version code works as you want, Isn't your problem solved already?

Comment: my question is why we can't access oldObj's value whit newObj.oldObj[i] instead of newObj[oldObj[i]]

Comment: You got wrong understanding of the syntax. `newObj.oldObj[i]` means, first read the key named "oldObj" from `newObj`, let's name the value `temp`, then read the key that is stored in variable `i` from `temp`.

Comment: The equivalent bracket syntax would be: `newObj["oldObj"][i]`

Answer (score 1):

You might want to reconsider your data structure. It should be an array of objects.

> eg: [{name:"Mohammad",age:"29"}, {name:"John",age:"19"}]

However, the code would look like

```
const swap = Object.entries(obj).reduce((accum, [key, value]) => ({...accum, ...{ [value]: key } }), {})
```

Why your code didn't work?

> javascript computed properties

you tried with, **newObj.obj[i] = i**

instead it should be **newObj[obj[i]] = i**

You need to resolve the value for **[obj[i]]**

in this case,
newObj[obj[i]] becomes 29. but newObj.obj becomes newObj.29 which'll be undefined at this point.

rewriting your function would look like,

```
/* {name:"Mohammad",age:"29"} ==>>  {Mohammad:"name",29:"age"} */

const obj = {name:"Mohammad",age:"29"}

function objValue (obj){
        const newObj = {}
    
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
     newObj[value] = key
    }
    
    return newObj
}

console.log(objValue(obj))
```

Comment: in reference we see for access object's key has two way: object["keyName"] or object.keyName. and if key name does not exist, create at this time. now, in my code why  newObj[oldObj[i]] create key for newObj and newObj.oldObj[i] not create key and try ONLY for access, not create it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to think about the logic first,
If I needed to solve this I will make the object into two arrays and then convert them back to object by swapping there places like below:

```js
const object = {
    name:"Mohammad",
    age:"29"
};

function swap(obj) {
    const key = Object.keys(obj);
    const value = Object.values(obj);
    let result = {};
    value.forEach((element, index) => {
        result[element] = key[index];
    });
    return result;
}

console.log(swap(object));
```

Comment: I got a one-liner equivalent for you: `Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([a, b]) => [b, a]))`.